# Injecting named Guice singleton

Tags: java, dependency-injection, junit, guice

I have a simple POJO:

```
public class MyPOJO {
    @Inject
    private Fizz fizz;

    private Buzz buzz;

    // rest of class omitted for brevity
}
```

I would like to configure my Guice module such that there are two types of `Fizz`es that it injects:

1. A special, globally-singleton `Fizz` instance; and
2. Other (non-special) `Fizz` instances

I want `MyPOJO` to be injected with the special/singleton instance. So I modified my code:

```
public class MyPOJO {
    @Inject @Named("Special-Fizz")
    private Fizz fizz;

    private Buzz buzz;

    // rest of class omitted for brevity
}
```

Then in my module:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(Fizz.class).annotatedWith(
            Names.named("Special-Fizz"))
            .to(Fizz.class);

        // Other bindings here...
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    private Fizz providesFizz() {
        return new Fizz(true, "Special", 12.0);
    }
}
```

But when I try to unit test (JUnit 4.10) this:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Named("Special-Fizz") private Fizz specialFizz;

    @Test
    public void usingNamedShouldInjectSpecialFizz() {
        MyModule mod = new MyModule();
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(mod);

        specialFizz = injector.getInstance(Fizz.class);

        Assert.assertTrue(specialFizz != null);
    }
}
```

This passes. So far, so good. But then if I change the name of the `specialFizz` field:

```
    @Named("Special-Fuzz-This-Shouldnt-Work") private Fizz specialFizz;
```

And re-run the test, *it still passes*. Why?!? Where am I going astray here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very odd. Guice should complain if it can't find a `Named` binding that it's injecting. I'm a bit confused by your test, though. I don't know what `injector.inject` does. Do you mean `injectMembers`? It might make more sense to actually get an instance of your POJO and make sure that it's working the way you expect. Maybe something like:

```java
public class FizzTest {

  public static class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("Special-Fizz")
    public Fizz providesFizz() {
      return new Fizz(true);
    }
  }

  public static class Fizz {
    boolean special = false;
    public Fizz() {}
    public Fizz(boolean special) {
      this.special = special;
    }
  }

  public static class MyPOJO {
    @Inject @Named("Special-Fizz")
    private Fizz fizz;

    @Inject
    private Fizz otherFizz;
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    MyModule mod = new MyModule();
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(mod);

    MyPOJO pojo = injector.getInstance(MyPOJO.class);
    assertTrue(pojo.fizz.special);
    assertTrue(!pojo.otherFizz.special);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @condit (+1) - that was an error on my part in typing up this question. I've edited my original question to show that I'm actually calling `injector.getInstance`, not `injector.inject`. Does that change anything for you? Is `getInstance` not correct for me to be using here? If so, why, and what is? Thanks again!

Comment: In your test you're asking the injector for an instance of `Fizz` which it will always be able to provide you (because of your `@Provides` method). I think you want to get an instance of `MyPOJO` instead. Note that the `Fizz` you're getting is unrelated to the `Fizz` member of the test. So changing the `@Named` will have no effect in this case.

Comment: You nailed it. I just asked it to inject a `MyPOJO` and it correctly injected it's `Fizz` property with my special fizz. Mystery solved - just a poorly implemented test method. Thanks again!

Comment: @condit In your example, how did Guice initialise the `@Inject private Fizz otherFizz;` ? I don't see it intialised anywhere in the MyModule class.

Comment: @Anurag - To create `otherFizz` Guice is using constructor injection (by invoking the no argument constuctor). See: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections

Comment: I see. So Guice automatically does that even if we don't explicitly provide in it Modules. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Guice sees the `@Provides` method and happily uses that to inject the `Fizz`. If you want to have a special instance of `Fizz`, you can drop the annotations from the `providesFizz()` method and instead bind with

```
bind(Fizz.class)
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("Special-Fizz")
    .toInstance(providesFizz());
```

This way, you tell Guice exactly which `Fizz` to use as the "Special-Fizz", while still letting it inject `Fizz` "normally" otherwise.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried a setup like yours, but I have used one similar. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks @Bradley T. Hughes (+1) - **however** your suggestion doesn't change anything. The unit test still passes, regardless of what you name the `Fizz`. You mentioned something that I thought was interesting. You said "*I haven't actually tried a setup like yours...*", however, from your answer I deduce that you seem to be fairly comfortable using Guice. So it makes me wonder: *Is this a bizarre setup that I'm using?* I thought the *point* of Guice was to use Classes and Annotations together to pinpoint exactly what type/config you want injected...

Comment: ...so am I doing something here that is out of the ordinary? If so, why?!? Where am I misunderstanding the normal usage of Guice? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think it's a bizarre setup. And to be honest, I've not used Guice that much, so I'm certainly no expert. The difference is that the code I am working on uses the same annotation to inject two different types (one single instance of each).